# Cyclic deps in substrate?

Tags: error, learning

Out of curiosity, I'm running `$ rust-analyzer analysis-stats .` in my substrate repo root directory.

I'm getting reports about ~30 cyclic dependencies, similar to

```
[ERROR project_model::workspace] cyclic deps: frame_election_provider_support(CrateId(199)) -> frame_election_provider_solution_type(CrateId(198)), alternative path: frame_election_provider_solution_type(CrateId(198)) -> frame_election_provider_support(CrateId(199))
```

I'm wondering if this is a problem or not?
Should it be fixed or should I configure rust-analyzer to ignore it somehow?

I'm running this version: `rust-analyzer 1.64.0-nightly (897a7ec 2022-07-17)`

Comment: I think it _may_ be related to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12973) related to build.rs (there is a dup issue calling out cyclic deps). This was just "fixed" upstream in RA, so it should land in a release  and make it's way into the VSCode extension 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cyclic dependencies are not allowed by Rust in general.

I looked into the specific error that is being brought up here.

Package `frame-election-provider-support` has a dependency on `frame-election-provider-solution-type`.

But package `frame-election-provider-solution-type` only has a `dev-dependency` to `frame-election-provider-support`.

In this case, the cyclic dependency is right, and something that is explicitly allowed by the rust testing framework.

So in this case, no, nothing needs to be fixed afaik.